# Getting the dates of each month where max and min values are formed-python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data set for many dates. I would like to get the dates where the min from column A and max from column B value are formed in each month. Result needs to like below.

```
   |MinValue(Column A)|MinValueDate|MaxValue(Column B)|MaxValueDate|
   |------------------|------------|------------------|------------|
   |206.3             |26-12-2022  |222.65            |14-12-2022  |
   |203.2             |20-01-2023  |215.1             |03-01-2023  |
   |207.75            |14-02-2023  |202.1             |16-02-2023  |
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table have same number of datetime between min and max value, then take a look at this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "MinValue(Column A)": [226.8, 218.45, 205.55, 206.3, 203.2, 207.75],
    "MinValueDate": ["14-12-2022", "03-01-2023", "16-02-2023", "26-12-2022", "20-01-2023", "14-02-2023"],
    "MaxValue(Column B)": [222.65, 215.1, 202.1, 189.1, 196.3, 202],
    "MaxValueDate": ["14-12-2022", "03-01-2023", "16-02-2023", "26-12-2022", "20-01-2023", "14-02-2023"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                                                     # Initiate data
df1 = df[["MinValueDate", "MinValue(Column A)"]]                                            # Split into two dataframes
df2 = df[["MaxValueDate", "MaxValue(Column B)"]]

df1 = df1.rename(columns={'MinValueDate': 'datetime', 'MinValue(Column A)': 'A'})           # rename columns
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime'])                                           # convert first datetime from 'dd-mm-yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
df1 = df1.sort_values(by = ['datetime'])                                                    # sort first dataframe by datetime

df2 = df2.rename(columns={'MaxValueDate': 'datetime', 'MaxValue(Column B)': 'B'})           # rename columns
df2['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime'])                                           # convert second datetime from 'dd-mm-yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
df2 = df2.sort_values(by = ['datetime'])                                                    # sort second dataframe by datetime
df2 = df2[['B']]                                                                            # pick only B column in second dataframe

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)                                                           # merge two dataframe at the columns side
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')  # return the datetime to its original format : 'dd-mm-yyyy'
print(df)
```

Base on the code above, split of the dataframe is useful to make it the order right. `A` and `B`'s column order follow the value of each `datetime`. And then, merge it back and change the original format of `datetime` back. The result is like this:

| datetime | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14-12-2022 | 226.8 | 222.65 |
| 26-12-2022 | 206.3 | 189.1 |
| 20-01-2023 | 203.2 | 196.3 |
| 14-02-2023 | 207.75 | 202.0 |
| 16-02-2023 | 205.55 | 202.1 |
| 01-03-2023 | 218.45 | 215.1 |

Comment: Thanks Jordy for the help. But its not the same number of datetime between min and max  value. Its based on monthly datetime for example Jan would have 31 days, Feb 28/29, April-30 days like that. and the dataframe needs to be like the expected result. Can make index like Year+Month eg:-202211,202212,202301,202302

Comment: How about this?